# Codeigniter Email class inside a model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to use the Codeigniter Email class within a Model?

I have been trying to but it refuses to load the mail object. In general, are libraries allowed to be loaded into models?

**Code**

```php
<?php

class ClubInvitation extends DataMapper {
        
        var $table = "club_invitations";
        var $has_one = array("club");
        
        public function __construct($id){
            parent::__construct($id);
            $this->load->library('email');
        }
        
        public function inviteEmailToClub($email, $club, $message){ 
            $invite = new ClubInvitation();
            $invite->email = $email;
            $invite->code = random_string('unique', null);
            //$invite->save($club);
            
            $club->ClubAdmin->limit(1);
            $mainClubAdmin = $club->ClubAdmin->get()->User->get();
            $data['club'] = $club;
            $data['message'] = $message;
            $data['club_leader'] = $mainClubAdmin;
            $data['invite_code'] = $invite->code;
                        
            $email_body = $this->WBLayout->emailTemplate('invited_to_club', $data);
            $this->email->from($mainClubAdmin->User->getAccount()->email, $club->name);
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject($club->name.' has invited you to join');
            $this->email->message($email_body);
            $this->email->send();
        }

}
```

Comment: yea, it can be loaded, can you show your code pls..

Comment: updated with all code, as you can see I am loading the email library in the constructor but when i attempt to use it I get the error that I am calling a function on a non object

Comment: also, I have a library autoloaded in the controller calling this model, but it is also null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, libraries are loaded in controller and accessed from there, not from models. You could just return the array of data from your model to controller and use email library from controller itself. If thats not feasible for you, then try doing:

```
public function __construct($id){
   parent::__construct($id);
}

public function inviteEmailToClub($email, $club, $message){
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $CI->load->library('email');
   .....
   $CI->email->from($mainClubAdmin->User->getAccount()->email, $club->name);
   ....
}
```